# How to fetch title and date from calendar shortcut

Tags: sirishortcuts

I am fetching data such as title and date from a specific calendar using shortcut[image]. i am trying to display event name and date in the same line then next date and event in next line. It is showing all events first and then date and time In different lines. But I want to display single event name and its date in the same line and then start with next new event name and date in the next line. This is what I tried can any one help ??

[image]